# String to JsonObject in java and return in as nested Json within Json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I need to convert a JSON string that is saved in the DB under "configValue" to a JsonObject and return it in the response as nested JSON. I tried most of the library but an exception is always triggered that can't convert to a JsonObject.

the dto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConfigurationDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private Long id; //by id too
    @NotNull
    private String version;
    @NotNull
    private String configName;
    @Lob
    @NotNull
    private String ConfigValue;

}
```

the entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private Long id; //by id too
    @NotNull
    private String version;
    @NotNull
    private String configName;
    @Lob
    @NotNull
    private String ConfigValue;

}
```

implementation:

```
    public ConfigurationDto getVersion(String version) throws ParseException,JSONException {

        Configuration configuration = configurationRepository.findByVersion(version);
//        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
//        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(configuration.getConfigValue());

//        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        return new ConfigurationDto(
                configuration.getId(),
                configuration.getVersion(),
                configuration.getConfigName(),
                configuration.getConfigValue()
        );
    }
```

Error Message:

```
 Value version of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First turn the JSON into a Java class (nb you have probably a typo in your example).

You can do this here for example: https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo

```
public class ConfigValue{
     public Mpgs mpgs;
     public Loyalty loyalty;
     public Database database;
}

public class Database{
    public Oracle oracle;
    public Mysql mysql;
    public Paging paging;
}

public class Loyalty{
}

public class Mpgs{
    @JsonProperty("MPGS_ACCEPT_VERSIONS") 
    public String mPGS_ACCEPT_VERSIONS;
    @JsonProperty("MPGS_URL_V61") 
    public String mPGS_URL_V61;
}

public class Mysql{
}

public class Oracle{
}

public class Paging{
    public int pageSize;
}

public class Root{
    public String ex1;
    public String ex2;
    public ConfigValue configValue;
}
```

Then turn the raw String from database to a ConfigValue object

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
ConfigValue conf = om.readValue(myJsonString, ConfigValue.class);
```

And feed into a Root object

```
Root r = new Root();
r.ex1 = "001";
r.ex2 = "002";
r.configValue = conf
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it other than creating classes?

Comment: `ObjectMapper().readValue(myJsonString, HashMap.class);` but you will lose all the domain model.

Comment: why would I want to keep the domain model? where HashMap can do everything for me?

Comment: Array can do all for you too ;-) As the most, it depends. I don't know your use case, this is one of many responses to your question